# To return multiple matches for multiple criteria in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need a solution wherein i have the following table

```
Q1  Pen $1.50 
Q2  Eraser  $2.00 
Q3  Paper   $1.70 
Q2  Pen $1.70 
Q1  Pen $3.00
```

When quarter = Q1 and Item is a Pen i need the sum of the dollar values which is $1.50+$3.00

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SUMIFS` function to calculate it:

`=SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,"Q1",B:B,"Pen")`
[image]

---

Other option could be a pivot table: set quarter and item as row labels, and add price to "values":

[image]